# Python Elasticsearch 7.05 indexing failing

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

I have created an index on my ES server via Kibana that looks like this

```
PUT export_control
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "content": {
        "type":        "text",
        "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result is

```
{
  "acknowledged" : true,
  "shards_acknowledged" : true,
  "index" : "export_control"
}
```

When I try to index a new document with the following command in python

```
col_names = df.columns
for row_number in range(df.shape[0]):
    body = dict([(name, str(df.iloc[row_number][name])) for name in col_names])
    es.index(index = 'export_control', doc_type="pdf_document", body = body)
```

I get the following error

```
RequestError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-247-6df868fd60f1> in <module>
      2 for row_number in range(df.shape[0]):
      3     body = dict([(name, str(df.iloc[row_number][name])) for name in col_names])
----> 4     es.index(index = 'export_control', doc_type="pdf_document", body = body)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py in _wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
     74             for p in es_query_params + GLOBAL_PARAMS:
     75                 if p in kwargs:
---> 76                     v = kwargs.pop(p)
     77                     if v is not None:
     78                         params[p] = _escape(v)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py in index(self, index, doc_type, body, id, params)
    317         "timeout",
    318         "timestamp",
--> 319         "ttl",
    320         "version",
    321         "version_type",

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py in perform_request(self, method, url, headers, params, body)
    316                     method = "POST"
    317 
--> 318                 # or as source parameter
    319                 elif self.send_get_body_as == "source":
    320                     if params is None:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py in perform_request(self, method, url, params, body, timeout, ignore, headers)
    183                 kw.update(
    184                     {
--> 185                         "cert_reqs": "CERT_REQUIRED",
    186                         "ca_certs": ca_certs,
    187                         "cert_file": client_cert,

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py in _raise_error(self, status_code, raw_data)
    123         )
    124         logger.debug("> %s", body)
--> 125         logger.debug("< %s", response)
    126 
    127         self._log_trace(method, path, body, status_code, response, duration)

RequestError: TransportError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', 'Rejecting mapping update to [export_control] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, pdf_document]')
```

Comment: What is the `body` ? It is valid JSON ?

Comment: @demas I have updated my question, to show the full index code I am using. It is a dict created from a pandas data frame. By the way, this code works fine, if I don't create the index in Kibana first. However, I need to use term_vectors, hence using Kibana.

Comment: Try to specify `doc_type` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in Elasticsearch types were removed recently - [some full definition of it](https://www.elastic.co/blog/moving-from-types-to-typeless-apis-in-elasticsearch-7-0), which means, that you could have only one type - called `_doc`, while you're creating second one - `pdf_document`.

You should use

```
es.index(index = 'export_control', doc_type="_doc", body = body)
```